# Module in /etc/modules not loaded at boot

Tags: ubuntu, boot, kernel-modules

I'm trying to ensure that a driver module `ch34x.ko` is loaded every time I boot my device so that it correctly identifies and mounts a USB to serial converter I am using.

When I mount the module manually via `insmod ch34x.ko` the driver is shown by `lsmod | grep ch` and when I un-plug and re-plug by serial converter `dmesg` correctly identifies it and attaches it to `/dev/ttyUSB0`.

Following this I copied the kernel object into `/lib/modules/ \` uname -r`/kernel/drives` and added "ch34x" to the bottom of /etc/modules and restarted. However post restart lsmod doesn't show the module and the converter is not recognise.

I had a look around and all the advice I could find was to  put the module name into /etc/modules (or/etc/modules-load.d which I also tried).

The Device is an Nvidia Jetson Nano running Linux 4 Tegra 4.9. However this OS is based on Ubuntu 18.04. I cant find any advice specific to this issue in L4T so I assume its an ubuntu problem.

running `sudo modprobe ch34x` after reboot produces

`modprobe: FATAL: Module ch34x not found in directory /lib/module/4.9.140-tegra`

I have also attempted added ch34x.ko into the above directory rather than./kernel/drivers (from the above path) and I receive the same error.

Comment: If you run `sudo modprobe ch34x` after restarting, does it produce any error messages? (Please add this information into your original question.) Also, check your directory path. The literal `/lib/modules/uname -r/kernel/drives` is not the same as the shell command expansion of `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers`: the `$(uname -r)` part means "this gets replaced with the output of the `uname -r` command when the command is executed in a POSIX-compliant shell."

Comment: Information added to the question, yes when ran as /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drives it correctly returns the kernel name however does not let me type these ` marks in the question without replacing them as HTML for inline code. apparently escaping them \` doesn't work properly either which is annoying

Comment: After a restart, is the `ch34x.ko` file still in the directory you placed it into? Does it help if you run `sudo depmod` before `sudo modprobe ch34x`? (It might be that L4T uses an old or reduced-functionality version of `modprobe` that won't automatically update the module dependency information if it's not up to date.)

Comment: Hi, yes the .ko persists after reboot. And yes, after running depmod modprobe returns with no error